# How to check screen resolution in HTML

Tags: html, textbox, screen, resolution

How can I check screen resolution of a screen when my website is opened by it, to adapt the text-box dimensions for it?

Answer (score 1):

To measure width : screen.width
To measure height : screen.height

```
<script>
    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    var screenHeight = screen.height;

    console.log(screenWidth);
    console.log(screenHeight);
</script>
```

If you are developing responsive application try bootstrap. If you use bootstrap it will provide you different classes to fit a field into screen size.
Reference:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: And how can I use this dimensions for my web page?